# Trying to use a loop to make a method call after splitting a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a program that implements a linked list, in order to read polynomials from a file and put them into linked list nodes. I've now read the polynomials from the file, split them into their coefficients and exponents. Now my task is to find a way to call an add function in a `Polynomial` class that creates the nodes. This function takes two integers as an argument. How can I write code that takes the two terms and calls the method without running into an error? Constants will have no exponent, only a coefficient.

The ultimate goal is to call a method that creates a node. This method accepts two integers as an argument, the coefficient and exponent of each term in the polynomial.

Here's what I have so far in my `main` method. I've written some print statements in certain areas of my loops to better understand what's happening at various places in the program.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Proj2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial list1 = new Polynomial();
        File file = new File("polynomials.txt");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] term = line.split("[+]");
                for (int i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
                    while (term[i] != null) {
                        String[] s3 = term[i].split("[ ^//x]");
                        for (int u = 0; u < s3.length; u++) {
                            System.out.println(s3[u]);

                            // put the data into the polynomial class starting here with the add
                            // method
                            // constants get an exponent of 0 and monomials get an exponent of 1 see
                            // email
                            System.out.println("each element of the polynomial is divided here");
                            // Integer r = Integer.getInteger(s3.toString());
                            // System.out.println(r);
                        }
                        System.out.println("each term is divided here");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("each line/polynomial is divided here");
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the file the program is reading from:

```
4x^2+2x^1+3
5x^3+15
2x^2+2x^1+5
```

I've tried several different loops, several different methods of converting the `String`s to `Integer`s, such as:

```java
Integer r = Integer.getInteger(s3.toString());
```

and passing `r` as argument to my method call, but I can't figure out how to iterate through in a way that makes sense, or as of right now, even a way to get `r` equal anything other than a null value. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted is not trying to do any of the things your post is talking about. It would help a lot if you narrowed your problem down to a specific issue instead of what looks like a entire homework assignment.

Comment: What do you think this does?  `split("[ ^//x]")`

Comment: @Daedron I want to add a method call in the second for loop of the format 'poly.add(s3[u], s3[u]);' where the arguments are coefficients. I guess to clarify my question is how to a use a loop to fill the arguments for a method call? And  re the split, I'm hoping that it splits a string into numbers separated by the ^ and x characters. Best regards, any input would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... How can I write code that takes the two terms and calls the method ..."*

Create a *class* to hold the each *polynomial term*.

Subsequently, create a *static* *method* to parse a *term*.

```java
class Polynomial {
    BigDecimal coefficient;
    BigInteger power;

    static Polynomial parse(String s) {
        Polynomial p = new Polynomial();
        int i = s.indexOf('^');
        if (i == -1) p.coefficient = new BigDecimal(s);
        else {
            if (i != 1) p.coefficient = new BigDecimal(s.substring(0, i - 1));
            p.power = new BigInteger(s.substring(i + 1));
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

From here, use a 2-dimensional *LinkedList* to contain each *polynomial expression*.

```java
LinkedList<LinkedList<Polynomial>> l = new LinkedList<>();
String f = "polynomials.txt";
try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
    String s;
    LinkedList<Polynomial> t;
    while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
        t = new LinkedList<>();
        for (String v : s.split("[+*-]")) t.add(Polynomial.parse(v));
        l.add(t);
    }
}
```

Output

```
coefficient = 4, power = 2
coefficient = 2, power = 1
coefficient = 3, power = null

coefficient = 5, power = 3
coefficient = 15, power = null

coefficient = 2, power = 2
coefficient = 2, power = 1
coefficient = 5, power = null
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!!! I really appreciate the help, especially with parsing the strings, I've found it complicated. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @Abra, I added an _i != 1_ check.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.
You first need to split the [polynomial] string into terms where the terms are delimited by the plus sign, i.e. `+`.
Note that `+` is a [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) metacharacter so you need to escape it when you want to [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the string of the polynomial into terms.

After splitting into terms, you want to extract the coefficient and the exponent from each term.
The coefficient is the number before the `x` and the exponent is the number after `x^`. Of-course a term may not contain `x` and may not contain `^` so you need to handle those cases as well.
In the below code, I use method [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to locate the coefficient and the exponent and then I use method [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) to extract both of them.

I am unfamiliar with class `Polynomial` so I assume it is a class that you wrote, however I couldn't find the code for that class in your question so I wrote my own. In the below code, `Polynomial` is a singly-linked list where each node in the list is an instance of class `Term` (which is another class I wrote) and a `Term` contains both a coefficient and an exponent.

In the below code, I read a line from the text file, split it into terms, extract the coefficient and exponent from each term, create a `Term` instance and add it to the `Polynomial` instance.
The `print` statements in the below code are only for debugging purposes.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Proj2 {
    public static void poly() {
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("polynomials.txt"))) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                Polynomial polynomial = new Polynomial();
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] terms = line.split("\\+");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
                boolean first = true;
                for (String term : terms) {
                    int begin = term.indexOf('^');
                    int exp;
                    if (begin > 1) {
                        exp = Integer.parseInt(term.substring(begin + 1));
                    }
                    else {
                        exp = 0;
                    }
                    int start = term.indexOf('x');
                    int coeff;
                    if (start == 0) {
                        coeff = 1;
                    }
                    else if (start > 0) {
                        coeff = Integer.parseInt(term.substring(0, start));
                    }
                    else {
                        coeff = Integer.parseInt(term);
                    }
                    if (first) {
                        first = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(", ");
                    }
                    System.out.printf("%d|%d", coeff, exp);
                    Term t = new Term(coeff, exp);
                    polynomial.addTerm(t);
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(polynomial);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        poly();
    }
}

class Term {
    private final int  coefficient;
    private final int  exponent;
    private Term  next;

    public Term(int coeff, int exp) {
        coefficient = coeff;
        exponent = exp;
    }

    public Term getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Term term) {
        next = term;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%dx^%d%s",
                             coefficient,
                             exponent,
                             (next != null ? "+" : ""));
    }
}

class Polynomial {
    private Term  start;

    public void addTerm(Term term) {
        if (start == null) {
            start = term;
        }
        else {
            Term temp = start.getNext();
            Term last = start;
            while (temp != null) {
                last = temp;
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            last.setNext(term);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Term temp = start;
        while (temp != null) {
            sb.append(temp);
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the output when using the sample polynomials file in your question.

```
4x^2+2x^1+3
[4x^2, 2x^1, 3]
4|2, 2|1, 3|0
4x^2+2x^1+3x^0
5x^3+15
[5x^3, 15]
5|3, 15|0
5x^3+15x^0
2x^2+2x^1+5
[2x^2, 2x^1, 5]
2|2, 2|1, 5|0
2x^2+2x^1+5x^0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!! This really helped me understand the mechanics of how to get the two integer values into the method call while keeping everything inside the loop. I really really appreciate this!!

Comment: @mat515 you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer or up-voting it (or both).